# How to use WHERE in an IF satement

Tags: t-sql

I would like to do the following:

```
IF [Question ID] = 'Q1' AND [Textual Answer] = 'Satisfied' 
THEN [Textual Answer] WHERE [Antwoord-ID] = [Antwoord-ID] AND [Question ID] = 'Q3' END
```

How can I include a WHERE in an IF statement?

Comment: How can [Question ID] be 'Q1' and 'Q3' at the same time?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to achieve? I mean, the general idea.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL syntax is [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

```sql
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN [Question ID] = 'Q1' AND [Textual Answer] = 'Satisfied' THEN [Textual Answer]
   END 
WHERE [Antwoord-ID] = [Antwoord-ID] 
AND [Question ID] = 'Q3'
```

However, as @AhmedShefeer points out, this will always be NULL as you're trying expecting `[Question ID]` to `'Q1'` and `'Q3'` at the same time

Comment: Thank you very much. The data contains pivoted survey data. So each filled in survey has the same Question ID. That’s why I wont get NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code- You can use IIF() Function in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
   IIF( ([Question ID] = 'Q1' AND [Textual Answer] = 'Satisfied'), [Textual Answer] ,'') AS [Answer] --Give your else case instead of ''
WHERE [Antwoord-ID] = [Antwoord-ID] 
AND [Question ID] = 'Q3';
```